# TYPO3 RealUrl - shorten extbase detail path to second level

Tags: typo3, extbase, realurl

I have an own Plugin for Jobs with a list and a show View (on the same page).
I entered my params in the "postVarSets" in the realurl_conf.php (grouped by "job-view") and so my Links look like following:

**/jobs** - List View

**/jobs/job-view/show/Job/testjob** - Detail View

---

Now i can shorten my path with the "encodeSpURL_postProc":

```
$params['URL'] = str_replace('job-view/show/Job', 'job-detail', $params['URL']);
```

and decode by

```
$params['URL'] = str_replace('job-detail', 'job-view/show/Job', $params['URL']);
```

**/jobs** - List View

**/jobs/job-detail/testjob** - Detail View

---

But i want my Detail View to look like:

**/jobs/testjob**

But I can't use

```
$params['URL'] = str_replace('jobs/job-view/show/Job', 'jobs', $params['URL']);
```

because the decode

```
$params['URL'] = str_replace('jobs', 'jobs/job-view/show/Job', $params['URL']);
```

would also try to decode the List View back.

---

So, is it possible to shorten the URL path of the detail page to the second level?

Comment: did you tried to use switchableControllerActions ?

Comment: I don't know how switchableControllerActions have something to do with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is very easy to achieve using a combination of `fixedPostVars` and TS conditions.

Assuming that your extensions's parameters are something like `tx_jobs_list`, you will have the following in the realurl config:

```
'fixedPostVars' => [
   $jobDetailPagePid => [
        [
            'GETvar' => 'tx_jobs_list[uid]',
            'lookUpTable' => [
                ...
            ]
        ],
        [
            'GETvar' => 'tx_jobs_list[controller]',
            'noMatch' => 'bypass'
        ],
        [
            'GETvar' => 'tx_jobs_list[action]',
            'noMatch' => 'bypass'
        ],
   ],
],
```

`$jobDetailPagePid` must be a page id. You cannot use `_DEFAULT` here.

You also need TS conditions for the detail page:

```
[globalString = GP:tx_jobs_list|uid = /\d+\]
config.defaultGetVars {
    tx_jobs_list {
        controller = List
        action = single
    }
}
[global]
```

That's all.

Comment: Good and performant solution. There‘s a requirement one should mention, though: `list` and `show` need to run (on the same page) within the same plugin / switchableControllerAction. If you need a dedicated page or the extension enforces separate plugins for `list` and `show` for whatsoever reason this won‘t help.

Comment: I also have an ajax url on my detail page - this one would also use the default single action - can I exclude ajax urls somehow?

Comment: @undko, not true. We use it on different pages in a number of projects.

Comment: @PhilippParzer, yes, you still can use `valueMap` but keep `noMatch` and do not add single to `valueMap`.

Comment: @DmitryDulepov I was referring to Philipp‘s requirements, he wants `/jobs` for list and `/jobs/job-title` for single - this can‘t be achieved on different pages with your proposal, can it? If so, how?

Comment: @undko My config will do exactly that. Default action for the plugin on the `/jobs/` will be `list`. If uid of the article is given, TS conditions will add `single` action parameter and invoke `single` action. No problem.

Comment: @DmitryDulepov of course, you‘re right. Didn‘t catch it in the first run, sorry :-)

Answer (score 0):

Take a closer look at the documentation: https://github.com/dmitryd/typo3-realurl/wiki/Configuration-reference#fixedpostvars
Maybe this can help you.

I never had to change the decode/encode functions to get what I need.

Comment: the URL in this case would be: /listPage/newsDetail/Testnews - but I want it to be: /listPage/Testnews

Comment: @philipp-parzer would `/newsDetail/Testnews` be acceptable for you? That‘s the way I usually go.

Comment: that is the point of my question - is it possible to get rid of the path "newsDetail"?

Comment: what I was suggesting is going for `/jobs` for the list and `/job/job-title-slug` for the single view. I consider this the most "speaking" way of creating uris as it uses correct grammatical number. Unfortunately fails for `news`, at least in English :-(.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `encodeSpURL_postProc` and `decodeSpURL_preProc` in your real_conf.php file like below.

```
'encodeSpURL_postProc' => array('user_encodeSpURL_postProc'),
'decodeSpURL_preProc' => array('user_decodeSpURL_preProc'),

function user_encodeSpURL_postProc(&$params, &$ref) {
   $params['URL'] = str_replace('jobs', 'job-view/show/Job/', $params['URL']);
}
function user_decodeSpURL_preProc(&$params, &$ref) {
   $params['URL'] = str_replace('job-view/show/Job/', 'jobs', $params['URL']);
}
```

Comment: first of all, you switched the two functions - but the main problem is, that this path would also overwrite the list View path which is "/jobs"